# Directory not creating other than WEB-INF & META-INF in WAR using Maven pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, web-applications, directory-structure

I need to create war for my spring framework project using maven(pom.xml) mvn clean install command. My Project SpringMVC folder contains jsp and src folder
all folder in src is creating inside the web-inf but i need to create jsp and other folder outside web-inf.

pom.xml build tag code

```
<build>
    <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>resource2</directory>
          </resource>
          </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In war file jsp folder not creating near web-inf. I don't know what else to try.

My Expected Output Folder Structure

```
SpringMVC.war
 |-- META-INF
 |   |-- MANIFEST.MF
 |   `-- maven
 |       `-- com.example.projects
 |           `-- documentedproject
 |               |-- pom.properties
 |               `-- pom.xml
 |-- WEB-INF
 |   |-- classes
 |   |   |-- com
 |   |   |   `-- example
 |   |   |       `-- projects
 |   |   |           `-- SampleAction.class
 |   |   `-- images
 |   |       `-- sampleimage.jpg
 |   `-- web.xml
 |-- external-resource.jpg
 |-- image2
 |   `-- external-resource2.jpg
 |-- index.jsp
 `-- jsp
     `-- websource.jsp
```

Comment: Can you show you folder layout and which directory you like to put into the war file ?

Comment: Pls edit your answer, dont post it as a command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use maven-antrun-plugin for creating directory and copying files.

```
    <plugin>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>generate-locator</id>
<phase>process-sources</phase>
<configuration> 
<tasks>
<mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/${project.version}/jsp" />
<copy todir="${project.build.directory}/${project.version}/jsp">
<fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/jsp" />
</copy>
</tasks>
</configuration>
<goals>
<goal>run</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you put the jsp's in the wrong directory.

Typicaly the jsp resist in this folder

```
\ROOT\src\main\webapp
```

where ROOT is the folder where the pom.xml resist.

@see also: [maven webapp to place jsps in /WEB-INF/jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873140/maven-webapp-to-place-jsps-in-web-inf-jsp)

Comment: I need to create in this folder structure only, is it possible in maven to do like this?